# User Interface for Private docker Registry

Tags: user-interface, ssl, docker, docker-registry

I have my private docker registry. But it's difficult to manage for some people who don't know Docker. So I want to use a UI for my registry.
I found this [Docker registry UI](https://github.com/atc-/docker-registry-ui) on github. 
My registry is using selfsigned certificates so using SSL. 
How do I have to configure this for my registry.

At the moment my registry is started with:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name regdomain.com\
  -v `pwd`/auth:/auth \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" \
  -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd \
  -v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key \
  registry:2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `docker` command you posted uses a `v2` registry, the project from `atc-` has still an [open issue](https://github.com/atc-/docker-registry-ui/issues/141) about support for `v2`.

*Possible alternatives...*

#### registry:0.9 `v1`

You may try [kwk/docker-registry-frontend](https://github.com/kwk/docker-registry-frontend/tree/v1-deprecated) (v1-deprecated branch) as an alternative for `v1` registries.

#### registry:2 `v2`

For `v2` you could try:

- [kwk/docker-registry-frontend](https://github.com/kwk/docker-registry-frontend) (master)
- [Portus](https://github.com/SUSE/Portus)

Answer (score 0):

I used all of mentioned docker-registry-frontends before, but with all respects to the Authors, those UIs was not "enough" for me.
So, this is the reason, why I use my own [frontend for private registry](https://github.com/Evedel/bow), you may try it from github or dockerhub.
Also you can find interface screenshots there.